# Netgear GS748Tv3 associate ports to vlans

Tags: switch, vlan, netgear-prosafe

I use a **Netgear 48-port switch GS748T**. I'm trying since yesterday to configure VLANs. So I added different vlans associated with their ID knowing the VLANs type is **port-based**.

[image]

After associating ports such as VLANs and saved my configuration, when I go to the page that allows me to view the MAC address table, I notice that all ports are always associated to the `VLAN 1` (default), as you can see in the picture below, while some should be associated with vlan 2, in this example.

[image]

How to solve this problem and allow these ports to be associated to the VLAN n°2?

Comment: What steps did you take to associate a port with a VLAN?

Comment: @RonMaupin **1**. Add a new vlan, **2**. In `vlan Membership`, click on the port I want to be associated to the vlan. And still all ports are associated to the default vlan and not the new vlan (for the port I want to change the vlan)

Comment: According to the manual, you click on the VLAN ID, select the ports you wish to be in that VLAN, then click Apply to activate it. That is for access ports. You aren't trying to add these at 802.1Q Tag VLAN ports are you?

Comment: @RonMaupin Indeed, I haven't tried the second option, but as the port-based doesn't seem to work (I have followed the documentation), maybe I have to use the IEEE 802.1Q encapsultation ?

Comment: Using the tagging feature will create a trunk port, and I doubt you want that. You may need to contact the manufacturer. You may have a bad code version that needs to be upgraded.

Comment: @RonMaupin Ok, thank you for your help. Indeed, I just need to add ports to vlans, no need any trunk ... And the firmware is the last I can get :( Maybe a bug in this. No luck. Ok, thank you anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you might be experiencing a bug which doesn't show the proper VLANs port membership, so check this out and see if a different browser helps: http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/23841/~/the-vlan-and-lag-configuration-screens-do-not-display-correctly-on-my-switch.
Second, make sure you are adding the VLANs correctly by verifying with the user guide that you have done the required steps properly.  You can find the user guide on the [GS748T Downloads Page](http://downloadcenter.netgear.com/en/product/GS748TS#searchResults).
If this still isn't working, I would suggest trying 801.q VLANs.  The important thing to know when using 802.1q VLANs, is to set each port to "untagged" mode, assign a VLAN, and set the PVID per-port to the same VLAN ID.  This should allow you to create separate VLANs on your Netgear switch.  Make sure you keep at least one port on VLAN 1 so that you can still connect to the management interface.  Of course make sure you have a router that can route between these separate networks, and either connect a port from each VLAN into this router, or create a "tagged" port carrying multiple VLANs to this device.

Comment: OW Thank you very much for your answer ! What a joy to see properly (with Firefox 3.5.6). Thank you for your answer very detailled !

Answer (score 1):

For thoses having the vlan membership bug on modern browsers and not willing to use and outdated browser, here's a little trick :

- Open the switch web admin panel
- Open the developer console
- Paste IXML.serialize = function(d) { return d?d.outerHTML:null; } in the console to overwrite their buggy function

The VLAN membership/LAG membership pages should be working now.

Best,
Thomas